# Angular Material - Customize md-slider draghead text

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, slider, material-design, angularjs-material

I have a slider in my Angular Material app, which has values that range from 0.0 to 1.0, with increments of 0.1. These are the values that I need in my model, but from the UI, I want the slider to display range 0 to 10 with increments of 1, or maybe a percentage value if that's possible. Is there any way to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom display texts are not yet natively supported by Angular Material Design. Such a [feature was proposed back in 2014](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/623), but unfortunately no one implemented it and the proposal was finally closed in April this year.

As any further feature development efforts are moved towards material 2, I currently see no chances for such a feature to be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [documentation](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdSlider), At first you need to set `md-discrete` directive of md-slider tag to true to make the slider steps discrete, then set the `step` directive to value that you want to increment each step.
Regards